# Chrome is giving me the wrong URL in it's 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error message

Tags: cors, http-headers

I am on a webapp hosted from a developer's machine, at `xyz.devteam.mycompany.com:8443`. This web app connects to another system at `my-service-test.mycompany.com`. Then I use the same web app hosted elsewhere (say `my-webapp-test.mycompany.com`) and I get an error message that says:

```
"Failed to load my-service-test.mycompany.com/token: 
    Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    Origin 'xyz.devteam.mycompany.com:8443' is therefore not allowed access."
```

Why is the previous URL in the error message?

Comment: the `Origin` is where the call originated from, its the original url location

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Yes, but in the error message it's the wrong `Origin`, it's the one hosted from the developer's machine even if I'm not looking at that instance.

Answer (score -1):

Use the 'Vary: Origin' header to prevent this accidental [cache poisoning](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/151590/11640).

Chrome has cached the response from `xyz.devteam.mycompany.com:8443` to `service-test.mycompany.com`, and it trying to use the same response for the request from `my-webapp-test.mycompany.com` this is not allowed due to the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.